# ask Logon info again

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, dataset

I created a report by using crystal report. I used ado.net connection for this. I created a dataset and joined report.

In coding veiw

```
Dim Rpt As New ReportDocument
Dim ClientAdp As New ClientTableAdapters.ClientsTableAdapter
Dim ClientDt As New Client.ClientsDataTable

ClientAdp.Connection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CurrentConnection").ConnectionString)
ClientAdp.Fill(ClientDt)

Rpt.Load(Server.MapPath(ADONET_REPORT_FILE))
Rpt.SetDataSource(CType(ClientDt, DataTable))
Rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("123", "123")
ReportViewer.ReportSource = Rpt
```

This is OK in first load time. And when I clicks print button in report view, the report view ask logon information. How can I fit this

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `TableLogOnInfo` for each table within your report not just the Report.

```
Dim logOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo
For Each tbCurrent As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In Rpt.Database.Tables
    logOnInfo = tbCurrent.LogOnInfo
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "MyDatabaseName"
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "UserId"
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "secretpassword"
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SQLServer"
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL
    tbCurrent.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo)
Next
```

I have [a blog post here](http://bdgr.co/gjeJbz) which details this in full (It's written in C# but the same principles apply for VB.NET)

Comment: This is Ok in first time load. When the report is shown, I clicks the report button. In this case, the report view ask log on info.